# ID3v2 tag for mp3 using C++

Tags: c++, id3v2

I need to read the id3v2 tag of mp3 file and cout its information using C++. some guidance if any one can provide.Sample code will he highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://taglib.github.io/. This sort of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library and don't reinvent the wheel. An example of such library is [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net).

Comment: how can we do this without using libraries?